# How can I change parameters into a text string in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, frequency, wavelet

I am trying to compute the Morlet wavelet transform (cmor) of a signal, but I have to do it several times with different parameters Fb and Fc. Is there a way to automate it? For example, I have to do the transform with: `cmor1-1, cmor1-2, ..., cmor1-10`.
I created a vector `Fc=1:10`, but I'm not able to replace Fc parameter into `cmor1-Fc`.
I tried this way:

```
morlet='cmor1-Fc'
for i=1:10
morlet(1,8:9)=i;
end
```

but it doesn't work (there appear squares instead of the number, and it would properly work only for 2-digit numbers.
Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide a little bit more information about your problem? Why do you have to do multiple transforms via multiple wavelets? In the meantime, please see [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```
text = 'cmor1-';
for i=1:10
     s{i}=[text num2str(i)];
end
```

where `s{i}` contains the string `cmor1-i`